# jQuery in Wordpress plugin not working for select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, forms

I am currently working on a plugin for `front-end user creation`, but it is little more specific to the website I am working on.

Part of the form that I am using to collect the information, it asks if the currently logged in user wants to create an "Admin", "Manager" or "User":

```
<select class="form-control" name="userType" id="userSelection">
    <option></option>
    <option id="adminValue" value="adminSelect">Admin</option>
    <option id="managerValue" value="managerSelect">Manager</option>
    <option id="userValue" value="userSelect">User</option>
</select>

<div id="adminSelect" class="typeselection" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="adminType" class="form-control">
            <option value="admin1">Admin1</option>
            <option value="admin2">Admin2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="managerSelect" class="typeselection" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="managerDepartment" class="form-control">
            <option value="manager1">Manager1</option>
            <option value="manager2">Manager2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="userSelect" class="typeselection" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="userDepartment" class="form-control">
            <option value="user1">User1</option>
            <option value="user2">User2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for the js file:

```
(function( $ ) {
'use strict';

    $('#userSelection').on('change',function(){
       ('.typeselection').hide();
       ('#' + this.val()).show();
    });

})( jQuery );
```

After choosing from the first select options `(name="userType")`, one of the 3 following `divs(id="adminSelect", id="managerSelect", id="userSelect")` would appear and allow for more specific options for the current user.

What I have currently in my code is not working with the js (saw a couple of different posts on here and other sites regarding this) though, and I have checked to make sure the file is being loaded and it is as well.

I used `Plugin Boilerplate Generator` to start out the plugin as well and placed the js in the `public/js/plugin-name.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the divs `display: none;`, which means it won't be displayed.

Instead of using `('#' + this.val()).show();` make a class called 'hidden' with the `display: none;` style. Give this class to the divs, and if one of the divs is clicked, use the following code:

```
$( "+"this.id ).removeClass( "hidden" );
```

This way you'll remove the `display: none;` property.

Comment: So, the js would be:  $('#userSelection').on('change', function(){ $( "+"this.id ).removeClass( "hidden" ); }); ?

Comment: I don't have an opportunity to test it right now, but it seems right. Give the 'hidden' class the `display:none; property and give the class to all three divs. If a selection is changed, the hidden class will be removed from the div, so it will become visible. You might also wanna take a look at the toggleClass and addClass functions.